# помогите с ошибкой в коде не понимаю я новичок

Tags: c#

[image: вот такая ошибка]

[image: мой код]

вот у меня код и мне надо что бы моя дорога в игре двигалась в верх или вниз без разнице но когда я пишу вот этот код то у меня не че не происходит помогите

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вангую, что вам нужно убрать `void` в строке `void road.FixedUpdate()`, кстати, откуда эта строка, где этот код? И код весь должен быть в виде текста, добавьте его в вопрос.

Comment: Текст надо вставлять текстом, а не скриншотами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ты два раза один и тот же метод написал Один через стрелочную, другую просто. Определись, что именно ты хочешь. Скорее всего тот, что сверху надо убрать или переместить код в тот, что ниже.

А, возможно, первый вообще должен быть просто `Update`. Но это знать должен только ты, что ты хочешь сделать.